# Redirect to different URL for different roles after login

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created 2 different roles in WordPress: `writer` and `copy-writer`, with only "read" capability (so they can change their profile only)

Also, I have developed a plugin.

So after the user logs into the ADMIN panel, they are taken to the "profile" page, but I need them to be taken to my plugin page

Any ideas on how to achieve the above functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action('login_redirect','my_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

check for the redirecting page (from where user is redirected after successful login), add conditional statement to check the user role and then redirect accordingly.

```
if($role=="whatever role you want to check")
  // redirect to plugin page
else
  // redirect to profile page (the default behavior)
```

Comment: don't like/want to change the default redirection, just want to add hook for specific role

Comment: yes, this does, but I need to know on which hook I should perform?

Comment: sorry i could not understand "hook". can you elaborate? are you asking where to hook this condition?

Comment: hooks are the part of WordPress, like 'init', etc.

Comment: oh ok... bro i dont have much experience in wordpress, thats why i cant help you in that. but the logic will be the same...